# ufunc 'divide' not supported for the input types...... error problem while trying to get the NumPy average

Tags: numpy, numpy-ufunc

I am new to Numpy and I have been trying to get the average of an array I derived from another array.

This is the code that have been giving me error: "ufunc 'divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'' "

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
​
cars = pd.read_csv('data/co2_emissions_canada.csv')
cars_makes = cars['Make'].to_numpy()
cars_models = cars['Model'].to_numpy()
cars_classes = cars['Vehicle Class'].to_numpy()
cars_engine_sizes = cars['Engine Size(L)'].to_numpy()
cars_cylinders = cars['Cylinders'].to_numpy()
cars_transmissions = cars['Transmission'].to_numpy()
cars_fuel_types = cars['Fuel Type'].to_numpy()
cars_fuel_consumption = cars['Fuel Consumption Comb (L/100 km)'].to_numpy()
cars_co2_emissions = cars['CO2 Emissions(g/km)'].to_numpy()
​
#the median of the cars_engine_sizes
print(np.median(cars_engine_sizes))

#the average fuel consumption for regular gasoline (Fuel Type = X), #premium gasoline (Z), ethanol (E), and diesel (D)? 

fuel_typesx=np.array(cars_fuel_types[cars_fuel_types=='X'])
print(np.average(fuel_typesx))

fuel_typesz=np.array(cars_fuel_types[cars_fuel_types=='Z'])
print(np.average(fuel_typesz))

fuel_typese=np.array(cars_fuel_types[cars_fuel_types=='E'])
print(np.average(fuel_typese))
```

please, what am i missing

Comment: why did you condense the error message?  Don't you think the ... part is important?

Comment: @hpaulj, I am so sorry. this is my first post here, I have updated it

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Looks like `cars_fuel_types` is an array containing strings like 'E'.  You can't an average of such an array.  You could count the number of particular values.

Comment: My guess is that instead of `fuel_typesx = np.array(cars_fuel_types[cars_fuel_types=='X']); print(np.average(fuel_typesx))`, you want something like `fuel_consumption_x = np.array(cars_fuel_consumption[cars_fuel_types=='X']); print(np.average(fuel_consumption_x))`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the FULL error message looks something like this:

```
In [753]: np.average(np.array(['A','B','C','A'],dtype=object))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [753], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 np.average(np.array(['A','B','C','A'],dtype=object))

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in average(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:380, in average(a, axis, weights, returned)
    377 a = np.asanyarray(a)
    379 if weights is None:
--> 380     avg = a.mean(axis)
    381     scl = avg.dtype.type(a.size/avg.size)
    382 else:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:191, in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, where)
    189         ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
    190 else:
--> 191     ret = ret / rcount
    193 return ret

TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

`cars_fuel_types` comes from a dataframe, and evidently contains strings like 'E'.  So it is `object` dtype.  Even if you select like values, you can't take an 'average'.

`average` takes the sum of values and divides by the count.  `sum` for python strings is concatenation, not some sort of math.

```
In [754]: np.sum(np.array(['A','B','C','A'],dtype=object))
Out[754]: 'ABCA'
```